# Getting rows from data.table's group by

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to create a list of vectors from 2 columns and an arbitrary number of rows of a data table. An example data table that is similar to what I'm working with is:

```
dt <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,4,4,3,5,7), 
                 b=c(12,13,14,15,15,16,17,22,18),
                 c=c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1),
                 d=c("cat1", "cat2", "cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat2", "cat1", "cat2"))


   a  b  c   d
 1: 1 12 1 cat1
 2: 2 13 1 cat2
 3: 3 14 1 cat1
 4: 4 15 1 cat1
 5: 4 15 2 cat2
 6: 4 16 1 cat3
 7: 3 17 1 cat2
 8: 5 22 1 cat1
 9: 7 18 1 cat2
```

I'd like to use a `by` statement to group the rows, and then create the list using a function. I haven't been able to get everything to work, though. Here's what I have:

```
create_kv <- function(x,y) {
  l <- list()
  i <- 1
  while (i <= length(x) & i <= length(y)) {
    each_c <- c(x[i], y[i])

    l[[i]] <- each_c
    i = i + 1
  }
  return(l)
}

for (each_a in unique(dt$a)) {
    for (each_b in dt[a == each_a,]$b) {
       ranks <- dt[a == each_a & b == each_b,]$c
       inv <- dt[a == each_a & b == each_b,]$d
       dt[a == each_a & b == each_b, `:=` (inv_flow = create_kv(ranks, inv))]
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, the loop doesn't correctly combine rows, even if I use `b="a,b"`. Instead, I'm getting:

```
    a  b c    d   inv_flow
 1: 1 12 1 cat1  1,cat1
 2: 2 13 1 cat2  1,cat2
 3: 3 14 1 cat1  1,cat1
 4: 4 15 1 cat1  1,cat1
 5: 4 15 2 cat2  2,cat2
 6: 4 16 1 cat3  1,cat3
 7: 3 17 1 cat2  1,cat2
 8: 5 22 1 cat1  1,cat1
 9: 7 18 1 cat2  1,cat1
```

What I'm hoping for is:

```
    a  b c    d   inv_flow
 1: 1 12 1 cat1  1,cat1
 2: 2 13 1 cat2  1,cat2
 3: 3 14 1 cat1  1,cat1
 4: 4 15 1 cat1  c(1,cat1), c(2,cat2)
 5: 4 16 1 cat3  1,cat3
 7: 3 17 1 cat2  1,cat2
 8: 5 22 1 cat1  1,cat1
 9: 7 18 1 cat2  1,cat1
```

So that there is one row for every `a,b` pair.

Comment: Your `dt` has rows `a,b,d,e` but you reference `dt$c` in the code. Which is it?

Comment: Your statement seems unclear and your do not say what result is desired. Best I can determine you want some sort of aggregation of something based on the value of the first column. Trying to read code for intent is difficult ... especially when it is not successful code.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you desire?

Comment: @jlhoward - Fixed! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @semerj - I've added what output I want, but let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @splitjack So row 4, column f would be a list with two values, correct? You could easily split a dataframe into a list by the unique values in column a and b (essentially an SQL group_by).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this is what you need?

```
dt <- dt[ , inv_flow := paste(c, d, sep=",")][, list(inv_flow = if (.N > 1) list(c(paste0("c(",inv_flow,")"))) else list(c(inv_flow))), by = "a,b"]

#   a  b            inv_flow
#1: 1 12              1,cat1
#2: 2 13              1,cat2
#3: 3 14              1,cat1
#4: 4 15 c(1,cat1),c(2,cat2)
#5: 4 16              1,cat3
#6: 3 17              1,cat2
#7: 5 22              1,cat1
#8: 7 18              1,cat2

str(dt)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  8 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ a       : num  1 2 3 4 4 3 5 7
# $ b       : num  12 13 14 15 16 17 22 18
# $ inv_flow:List of 8
# ..$ : chr "1,cat1"
# ..$ : chr "1,cat2"
# ..$ : chr "1,cat1"
# ..$ : chr  "c(1,cat1)" "c(2,cat2)"
# ..$ : chr "1,cat3"
# ..$ : chr "1,cat2"
# ..$ : chr "1,cat1"
# ..$ : chr "1,cat2"
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a small dataset, you can reshape your data as a `data.frame` and summarize it using `plyr`. Not a complete solution, but should get you started:

```
> df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,4,4,3,5,7), 
                   b=c(12,13,14,15,15,16,17,22,18),
                   c=c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1),
                   e=c("cat1", "cat2", "cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat2", "cat1", "cat2"))
> df$e <- as.character(df$e)

# create index you'd like to group by
> df$ab <- paste(df$a, df$b)

> library(plyr)
> ddply(df, .(ab), summarize, f = list(e), g = list(c))

    ab          f    g
1 1 12       cat1    1
2 2 13       cat2    1
3 3 14       cat1    1
4 3 17       cat2    1
5 4 15 cat1, cat2 1, 2
6 4 16       cat3    1
7 5 22       cat1    1
8 7 18       cat2    1
```

Comment: Unfortunately the data set I'm actually using is about 600,000 rows - hence data.tables.